# Javascript XMLHttpRequest Invalid Argument

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently working on a project trying to update a page reading from an XML file on our intranet server.  After doing some working I came up with the following code:

```
// IE7+
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
// IE6, IE5
else { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "VerifiedUrl+XML.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CheckBox")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "True"){
    document.getElementById("PartToUpdate").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TextBox")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Now I've tested this code on my localhost and it does in fact read from the correct file, displaying the updated information, but when I deploy it to the intranet, I get an "Invalid Argument" error.  (The XML file itself has been deployed and is referencing correctly).

**Edit:** I've recently found the problem, in that the path I was referencing apparently couldn't find the file itself.  So that brings up another question that someone might be able to shed light on:

```
//When referencing a file within the same folder, it works correctly.  
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Sample.xml", false);

//However, if I include the full path, it doesn't read correctly.  (Double slashes to escape correctly)
xmlhttp.open("GET", "\\\\Full\\Server\\Path\\Here\\Sample.xml", false);
```

Perhaps someone could shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path here is wrong:

```
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "\\\\Full\\Server\\Path\\Here\\Sample.xml", false);
```

You are using the wrong type of slashes for the internet, they would be correct on a file system. It needs to use a forward slash.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "//Full/Server/Path/Here/Sample.xml", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

should your path be something like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","./Path/Here/books.xml", false);  //for relative urls

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Path/Here/books.xml", false); //for absolute urls
```

and if its a non-http synchronous request

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'file:///home/user/file.json', false);
```

its not similar to your system path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Comment: Turns out both were part of the same origin.  I found a workaround for it, but decided to update the question for educational purposes.